# Index safety when using C# indexers?

Tags: c#

I'm coding a Vector class in C# and felt that indexers would be a good addition. Do I need to worry about the index being out of range?

Perhaps a code sample would be clearer:

```
    class Vector3f
    {
        public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Z = z;
        }

        public float X {get; set;}
        public float Y {get; set;}
        public float Z {get; set;}

        public float this[int pos]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (pos)
                {
                    case 0: return this.X; break;
                    case 1: return this.Y; break;
                    case 2: return this.Z; break;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                switch (pos)
                {
                    case 0: this.X = value; break;
                    case 1: this.Y = value; break;
                    case 2: this.Z = value; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Should I put a `default` case in my `switch` statements? What should it do?

Edit: It's a rather dumb question. The code above wouldn't even compile without the `default` case. Plus Jason's implementation below is superb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is much clearer and obviates the need to worry about range checking:

```
public enum Coordinate { X, Y, Z }
public float this[Coordinate coordinate] {
    get {
        switch(coordinate) {
            case Coordinate.X: return this.X;
            case Coordinate.Y: return this.Y;
            case Coordinate.Z: return this.Z;
            // convince the compiler that we covered everything
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("coordinate");
        }
    }
    set { 
        switch(coordinate) {
            case Coordinate.X: this.X = value; break;
            case Coordinate.Y: this.Y = value; break;
            case Coordinate.Z: this.Z = value; break;
        }
    }
}
```

But note that the coordinates are already public, so what's the point of the indexer?

Comment: The indexer would make it easier to loop over the Vector's coordinates, if needed.

Comment: And I definitely agree with Anton. I didn't think about enums at all.

Comment: To be on the safe side, you would still want to have a default with an ArgumentOutOfRangeException . enum variables can contain values that are not defined in the enum itself. for example Coordinate c= (Coordinate)10;

Comment: @dtroy: You're right, but more importantly it won't even compile without a `default` case as the compiler can't deduce that all codes paths return a value. See "Case 4" (pun intended?) on Four Switch Oddities (http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx) from Eric Lippert's blog.

Comment: @Aeolien: You could do this `public IEnumerable<float> CoordinateValues { get { yield return this.X; yield return this.Y; yield return this.Z; } }` if you only need the sequence of values (but don't need to modify them). If you do need to modify them, maybe someone can come up with something better than the following `public static IEnumerable<Coordinate> Coordinates { get { yield return Coordinate.X; yield return Coordinate.Y; yield return Coordinate.Z; } }` Then: `Vector3f v; foreach(var c in Vector3f.Coordinates) { v[c] = Math.Sin(v[c]); }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException like other containers (such as List) do. 
You can throw it from the default case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use an enumeration for this rather than an int indexer, that way, your code will be a lot clearer and you won't have to worry about outofrangeexceptions.  As it is, you're making it hard for people to see the intent of the code.

What do you need the indexer for anyway, why would someone use vector[0] instead of vector.X?

Comment: It would be easier to loop over the Vector using an indexer. And Enumeration is a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

If index not necessarily has to be **integer**, you can introduce **enumeration**, so compiler will guarantee that no invalid choices are used anywhere in code.